# Problem expanding math in arguments of en environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, expansion, newtheorem, expandafter

I want to redefine by hand a "restatable" environment for theorems. I have to do so because for some obscure reason the `jloganal` class (for the Journal of Logic and Analysis) mess it up: when restated, theorems have a new number corresponding to the section they are restated in. The journal suggests to "fake the environment" and rewrite it entirely. I do not like this "solution". By the way, this exercise is a good occasion to improve my Latex skills.

Here is an attempt:

```
        \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{xparse}

        \NewDocumentEnvironment{restate}{mmmb}{
            \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{#4} 
        \begin{#1}\label{#3}#4\end{#1}
        }{}
        \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

        \begin{document}
        \begin{restate}{thm}{thmun}{thmlabel}
           test-text $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=1$
        \end{restate}
        \thmun
        \end{document}
```

My problem is that `\mathbb{R}` leads to an error:

26: Undefined control sequence. \end
26: Undefined control sequence. \end
26: Undefined control sequence. \end
26: Undefined control sequence. \end
27: Missing { inserted. \thmun
: File ended while scanning text of \errhelp.

Also I am looking for a command that would behave like this: `\getEnvName{thm}` would write `Theorem`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In this specific instance you can use `\NewDocumentCommand{\thirdofthree}{ m m m }{#3} \NewDocumentCommand{\getEnvName}{ m }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\thirdofthree\csname #1\endcsname}` to retrieve **Theorem** when you issue `\getEnvName{thm}`. If you use other theorem-related packages, the process may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `\xdef`? You just want `\gdef`.

A better way would be to store alse `\begin{thm}` and `\end{thm}` and also locally redefining `\thethm` in the restatement, so the number agree.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}% no longer needed

\NewDocumentEnvironment{restate}{mmmb}{%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\gdef{#2}{%
    \begingroup
    \ExpandArgs{c}\renewcommand{the#1}{\ref{#3}}%
    \begin{#1}#4\end{#1}%
    \addtocounter{#1}{-1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \begin{#1}\label{#3}#4\end{#1}
}{}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{restate}{thm}{thmun}{thmlabel}
   test-text $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=1$
\end{restate}

\thmun

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `inputenc` with `utf8` is no longer needed, nor is `xparse`.

I used the “modern” `\ExpandArgs{c}\gdef{...}` instead of the clumsier

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname...\endcsname
```

For your particular setting, I wouldn't look for greater generality.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{restatable}[thm]{\protect\restatablename}
\newcommand{\restatablename}{}% initialize

\NewDocumentEnvironment{restate}{mmmb}{%
  % #1 = theorem header, #2 = symbolic name, #3 = label, #4 = contents
  \renewcommand{\restatablename}{#1}%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\gdef{#2}{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref{#3}}%
    \renewcommand{\restatablename}{#1}%
    \begin{restatable}#4\end{restatable}%
    \addtocounter{thm}{-1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \begin{restatable}\label{#3}#4\end{restatable}
}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{restate}{Theorem}{mainthm}{thmlabel}
   test-text $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=1$
\end{restate}

\begin{restate}{Proposition}{importantprop}{proplabel}
   test-text $0=0$
\end{restate}

\section{Proofs}

\mainthm

\importantprop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I still have a question : imagine I also have something like `\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}`. Now the problem is that there is no `prop` counter and thus the `the#1` would fail.

Comment: @QuentinG I don't think that anything that doesn't qualify as a theorem is worth restating.

Comment: Maybe but in my particular case there is a proposition that is useful to understand the point of my work while not being a strong result. Therefore, it is stated in the introduction and proved later. For the sake of readability, I prefer to restate it before the proof.

Comment: @QuentinG Look at the added code to see whether it fulfills your expectations.

Comment: @egreg It might also be worth looking at equation numbers inside the theorem. I do have a solution that works with your other restate env, but it uses regex so it a little slow. (here we opted to replace all labels inside the body of the thm by `\tag{\ref{key}}` assuming that they are all in math envs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to tackle this. Easiest is to use `\protected@xdef`:

```
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764
\NewDocumentEnvironment{restate}{ m m m b }{%
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname #2\endcsname{#4}%
  \begin{#1}\label{#3}#4\end{#1}%
}{}
\makeatother
```

But you can also avoid expansion of content (and therefore fix them in the definition) by temporarily `\let`ting them to `\relax`:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{restate}{ m m m b }{%
  \begin{#1}\label{#3}#4\end{#1}%
  % Temporarily deactivate macros for definition following below
  \let\mathbb\relax
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{#4}%
}{}
```